# Error CS7068 Reference to type 'ConfigServices' claims it is defined in this assembly, but it is not defined in source or any added modules

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I am working with a project in .net core 2.2 and I am trying to use one class from a reference coded in .Net 4.6 .

When I try to use it in my .net core project, it seems like intelisense recognizes the reference and I can nagivate to it, but it also tells me the error of the title.

I don't know what is going on but I think it could be some stuff about working with .net core and .Net 4.6.

This is the class (.Net 4.6):

```
    class ConfigServices : IEnumerable<ConfigService>, IEnumerable
    {
        public ConfigServices(IEnumerable<ConfigService> configServices, string activeService);

        public ConfigService ActiveService { get; }
        public bool IsEmpty { get; }

        public bool Contains(ConfigService service);
        public IEnumerator<ConfigService> GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Here is where I am getting the error (first line of method)(.Net core) :

```
            private async Task<string[]> configServicesToUse(string companyId, string serviceName)
            {
                var configServicesForCompany = (await UserInfo.ConfigServices(companyId)).Select(c => c.Name).ToArray();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(serviceName) ||
                    string.Equals(serviceName, "ALL", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return configServicesForCompany;
                }
                if (!configServicesForCompany.Contains(serviceName))
                {
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("No access to requested service");
                }

                return new[] { serviceName };
            }
```

This is the method called (.Net core):

```
        public static async  Task<ConfigServices> ConfigServices(string companyId)   
        {
            var configurationService = new ConfigurationService();
            var services =  await configurationService.ReadByCompanyId(int.Parse(companyId));

            return new ConfigServices(services, ActiveConfigService);
        }
```

The error I am getting is

> "Error CS7068 Reference to type 'ConfigServices' claims it is defined
>   in this assembly, but it is not defined in source or any added
>   modules".

I looked for answers but they were to specific for
frameworks and things I am not using.

I hope you can help me,
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the problem. This error was happening because I had the same namespace reference in my project as it was in one of the nuget packages. That was making Visual Studio to get really confused with the existance of the *ConfigServices* class.